# Streaming Video via JWPlayer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am trying to integrate HTTP Streaming of videos on an iPhone app that I am building. Within the app I am using the standard MPMoviePlayerViewController class.

I'm following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798).but I couldnot figure out how to pass URL and play using JWPlayer.
What URL do I need to point the player at in order to take advantage of default HTTP streaming provided by default by Bits on the Run.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT-01

After much hiting my head in  [JWPlayer Quick Start Guide](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28833/quick-start-guide) In my HTML , i'm writing this:-`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <p><div id="container"></div></p>
        <script>
            jwplayer("container").setup({
                                        playlist: [{
                                                   image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
                                                   sources: [{
                                                             file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-DZ7jSYgM.mp4",
                                                             width: 640,
                                                             height: 920
                                                             },{
                                                             file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
                                                             width: 320,
                                                             height: 460
                                                             }],
                                                   captions: [{
                                                              file: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/sites/default/files/jw6-captions.vtt',
                                                              label: 'English'
                                                              }]
                                                   }]
                                        });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

But on click play button it says Error loading media, file could not be played.  Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: How are you embedding the JW Player / BOTR into your iPhone App?

Comment: @Ethan:The same thing I could not figure out..If u have any idea share plz

Comment: @ethan : can u plz see my updated question, and if u can, plz give me some support.

Comment: Do you have a link that you can provide to where the issue is happening so I can take a look at it?